# Unexpected token error when using import command

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to setup firebase and firestore for the first time

I have been trying for a few days now to get this to work with no success.
Having followed all the docs on installing **Firebase** and firestore **SDK9** modular system I still get this error.

**Code**

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
```

**Error:**

> Unexpected token '{'. import call expects exactly one argument.

Comment: Can you share you package.json  and may be some more code?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you've set `module` type in `<script>` tag if you are using `import`, for example:

```
<script type="module" src="index.js"> </script>
```

And if you are using `nodejs` you should use the **latest version of nodejs** and indicate module type in `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "Testing app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Testing application",
  "main": "index.js",
  "type": "module"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have installed the latest Node Js again version v14.17.6 and installed Firebase again using npm.

I have added type: module to package.json.

First error I got was ...

TypeError: Module specifier, 'firebase/app' does not start with "/", "./", or "../".

I cleared this error by editing the index.js file and changing

```
import {initializeApp} from "firebase/app";
```

to

```
import {initializeApp} from "/node_modules/firebase/app";
```

In the index.html file I also added

```
    <script type="module" src="index.js"> </script>
```

I now get the error 'text/html' is not a valid JavaScript MIME type.

This is my package.json code

```
{
  "name": "firebasev9",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "type": "module",
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "IBP",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase": "^9.0.2"
  }
}
```

I am trying to follow the setup instructions on https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup but they never mention either of these errors I keep getting.

Comment: Did you solve it using your answer or it is a part and another details of your question?